# trouble with routing in AngularJS SPA

Tags: angularjs, single-page-application, angular-routing

I am a beginner to AngularJS and trying to build my first SPA. I have created the routes for a few pages and specified the links in the nav bar. the index file is

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#/"><img src="images/logo.png" height=30 width=41></a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#/">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/aboutus">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/menu">
                         <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"
                         aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                         Menu</a></li>
                     <li><a href="#/contactus">
                     <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
```

`

the routeProvider code is,

```
angular.module('confusionApp', ['ngRoute'])
.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        // route for the contactus page
        .when('/contactus', {
            templateUrl : 'contactus.html',
            controller  : 'ContactController'
        })
        // route for the menu page
        .when('/menu', {
            templateUrl : 'menu.html',
            controller  : 'MenuController'
        })
        // route for the dish details page
        .when('/menu/:id', {
            templateUrl : 'dishdetail.html',
            controller  : 'DishDetailController'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/menu'
        });
});
```

I have been loading the preview using gulp. When I load the page and click on the links, I am unable to change the templates on the page. I have tried looking for some answers but could not find one. Could some one help me out with this? And when I click on the links, the URL is being displayed as 
[But isn't it supposed to be "index.html#/contactus"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tyY5f.jpg)

However, I have tried manually changing the url (index.html#!/menu) and it worked fine. But the problem is that I do not understand why there are !/ in the url. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried doing an 'href="menu"' instead of '"/menu"'?

Comment: Yeah! tried it just now. It is still the same. Also in the URL image that I have included in the question, there is a "%2F" being included in the URL. Why is that happening? I am also wondering if it might be the reason for the URL not working properly..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Check this working demo :**

```js
 var app = angular.module('Routing', []);

 app
.controller('HomeController', function ($scope) {});

app
 .controller('AboutController', function ($scope) {});

app
.config(function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
    when('/home', {
        templateUrl: 'home.html',
        controller: 'HomeController'
    }).
    when('/aboutus', {
        templateUrl: 'about.html',
        controller: 'AboutController'
    }).
    otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home'
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="Routing">
<script type="text/ng-template" id="home.html">
    <h1> Home </h1>
</script>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="about.html">
    <h1> About </h1>
</script>

<div> 
    <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#/home"> Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#/aboutus">About</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I tried it...but it was the same. I found the problem. It was due to some error that happened while fetching the angular-route components through bower. It is working now. Thank you for your time!! :)

Comment: Can you mark this as a correct if you feel it is good answer. So, that it will be helpful for others also

Answer (score 0):

Try this. And there should be `ng-view` in the index.html

```
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="active"><a href="#">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="#aboutus">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#menu">
                     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"
                     aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                     Menu</a></li>
                 <li><a href="#contactus">
                 <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i> Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: in that case, go for angular's `ui-router`

Comment: no need to switch router if app is simple ... just use proper markup

Comment: what do you want to say? @charlietfl

Comment: Just saying that if you want to answer the answer needs to be correct

Comment: Read the docs if you don't know. I'm only pointing out that your guess is not correct

Comment: I found the problem. It was due to some error that happened while fetching the angular-route components through bower. It is working now. Thank you both for your time!! :)